# How to Display Number in Determined Length in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a very simple question. I am working on time and date now and I have an issue.

```
Text('Time is: ${date.hour}:${date.minute}')
```

When I write something like this, where date is a DateTime object, when minute is less than 10, it is displayed like

```
14:5
```

I want to display it in 14:05 format, in other words, in determined 2 digit length, like %.2d in C. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In flutter, we can use the DateFormat method for this purpose.

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

DateTime date = DateTime.now();
String formattedDate = DateFormat('HH:mm').format(date);

Text('Time is: $formattedDate')
```

Comment: It is very simple and clear. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with [padLeft method](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.15.1/dart-core/String/padLeft.html).

```
${date.hour.toString().padLeft(2, "0")}:${date.minute.toString().padLeft(2, "0")}
```

Comment: Thank you. I will remember this when I work specifically on Strings.